# Need to write a query to show staff full name number of specialties and name the new column as specialties

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query to show the staff full name, Number of specialties of all male with staff with more than one specialty.
Name the new Column Num of Specialties. 
Sort it by Staff Full Name

```
Table Describ
SQL> describ staff_speciality;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                             CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDDATE                                          DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> describ staff
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 FIRSTNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 LASTNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 ROLE                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 GENDER                                             CHAR(1)
 DATEJOINED                                NOT NULL DATE
 DATELEFT                                           DATE


COLUMN count(staffid) HEADING "Num of Specialities"
SELECT firstname || ' '|| lastname "Staff Full Name",
count(staffid) > 1
FROM staff, staff_speciality
ORDER By Staff Full Name;


COLUMN count(staffid) HEADING "Num of Specialities"
SELECT firstname || ' '|| lastname "Staff Full Name",
count(staffid) > 1
FROM staff, staff_speciality
ORDER By Staff Full Name;

Showing firstname and last name as Staff Full name
than counting how many staff with more than 1 entry
and sorting it by Staff Full name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use having count(..) > 1 and group by

```
SELECT firstname || ' '|| lastname "Staff Full Name",
count(staffid) "Num of Specialities"
FROM staff, staff_speciality
GROUP "Staff Full Name"
HAVING count(staffid)> 1
ORDER By "Staff Full Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INNER JOIN between the tables and group to get the number of specialities. 
 Finally with HAVING you restrict the results for those members of staff who have more than 1 speciality:

```
select 
  t.lastname || ' '|| t.firstname "Staff Full Name",
  count(s.specid) "Num of Specialities"
from staff t inner join staff_speciality s
on s.staffid = t.staffid
where t.gender = 'M'
group by t.staffid, t.lastname || ' '|| t.firstname
having count(s.specid) > 1
order by t.lastname || ' '|| t.firstname
```